# subset random quarter time data from a lubridate dataset

Tags: r, random, lubridate

How can you use match() function to generate random quarter(like Jan,Feb,March) and select a subset of your data: rows corresponding to generated random quarter and the 1st and 3rd column.

Assume we have a 12rows and 3columns time data, something like this:

```
      dates     strings    numbers
1  2017-01-31       S       5
2  2017-02-28       T       1
3  2017-03-31       C       8
4  2017-04-30       Q       2
5  2017-05-31       D       6
6  2017-06-30       X      12
7  2017-07-31       N      10
8  2017-08-31       Y       9
9  2017-09-30       P      11
10 2017-10-31       G       4
11 2017-11-30       F       7
12 2017-12-31       R       3
```

I mean it's easy to select random 3 rows in the dataset and subset only the column 1 and 3. like this,

```
df[sample(nrow(df), 3),c("dates","numbers")]
```

Therefore, i have,

```
        dates    numbers
5  2017-05-31       1
9  2017-09-30       4
11 2017-11-30      12
```

But how can you get random fiscal quarter by using match() to achieve like this,

```
        dates    numbers
1  2017-01-31       5
2  2017-02-28       1
3  2017-03-30       8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(qtr = format(as.yearqtr(dates), 'Q%q')) %>% 
   select(-strings) %>%
   sample_n(1) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   sample_n(3) %>% 
   select(-qtr)
```

Comment: it renders like this 
               dates numbers
1  2017-01-31       2
6  2017-06-30       7
10 2017-10-31       9

Comment: @xxyyzz  Based on your expected output, it is not clear what you are looking for

Comment: sry about the confusion. i think what i try to achieve is to let the subset randomly to be one of the quarters (1,2,3 or 4,5,6 or 7,8,9 or 10,11,12)

Comment: dates match the rows in three consecutive numbers (1,2,3 or 4,5,6 or 7,8,9 or 10,11,12)

Comment: @xxyyzz  It is not clear.  You said the subset randomly from one of the quarters and I did that.  Now, you are saying something different

Comment: well, it might sound nebulous but randomly quarter means you generate a fiscal quarter which is (1,2,3 or 4,5,6 or 7,8,9 or 10,11,12) in the context of dates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_year#Quarters

Comment: @xxyyzz  If you check my codes, it is generating the quarter from 'dates' itself i.e. `format(as.yearqtr(dates), 'Q%q'))`